# Build Variants with Ionic/Cordova

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Does Ionic/Cordova support build variants (like targets in Xcode or Product Flavors in Gradle)? I need to create Lite and Paid version off the same code base.

Comment: Interesting question... have you found a solution?

Comment: Sadly I have not.

Comment: have you found any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but it does require some manual work!

[Here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/environment-specific-configurations) the Capacitor docs guide you through the process of making a separate QA App.

Instead of a QA App you can follow the guide to make a `Paid` and `Lite` version of your App.

I can imagine that you want to disable certain features of the `Lite` version of the app. By checking the `NODE_ENV=qa` (in your case `NODE_ENV=lite`) you can disable certain features.